# Can't get line numbers in gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: sass, gulp

I have set up a gulp-ruby-sass task in gulp, with some options.
Options 'precision' and 'style' work as expected, but I get no debugInfo or lineNumbers in the css (I do get them with compass).
My gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

function errorLog(error)
{
  console.log(error.toString());
  this.emit('end');
}

// SASS
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      debugInfo   : true,
      lineNumbers : true,
      precision   : 6,
      style       : 'normal'
    }))
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I too have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. The solution was two-fold for me. If I added the lineNumbers option, it would fail with a file not found error. This is probably because I am compiling both normal css (with line numbers) along with a minified version.

I needed to add the "container" option in order for it to work correctly.

Here's what my working gulp tasks look like:

```
gulp.task('styles', function()

{
    return sass('app/assets/sass/app.scss', { style: 'expanded', lineNumbers: true, container: 'gulp-ruby-sass' })
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 15 version'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('styles-min', function()
{
    return sass('app/assets/sass/app.scss', { style: 'expanded', container: 'gulp-ruby-sass-min' })
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 15 version'))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

**NOTE:** The lineNumbers option is somewhat misleading because it's actually the path to the source sass/scss file AND the line number.